# Primefaces - Image Button

Tags: css, button, primefaces

I'm trying to make a button on Primefaces to be ONLY an image.

```
.bt_ligar{
   background: #fff url("../resources/img/img_phone.png") no-repeat !important;
   width: 15px;
   height: 15px;
}
```

But the css doesn't work and the Primefaces css is always used.

Somebody can help me?

Comment: JSfiddle required but this sounds like a specificity issue.

Comment: @Paulie_D It sure does sound like it, but the OP has `!important`, so there's more to it than simple specificity.

Comment: @thierseuller Are you sure the png file is in that location? Also, stupid question, but the png file is 15x15 pixels, right?

Comment: @MrLister The png was larger than that. I reduced the size and it worked. But I had to change the border too. I'm Not very good at CSS, thanks for the help.

Comment: @thierseuller Right; with the CSS you had there, you were only displaying the top left corner of the png.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about this:

```
<p:commandLink actionListener="#{yourBean.yourFunction()}"
        update=":mainForm:feedList">
    <p:graphicImage value="../resources/img/img_phone.png"/>
</p:commandLink>
```